# Automating wix small updates and minor upgrades

Tags: wix

I just read the following in the [wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/checking-for-oldies).

> For some strange reason, small updates
>   and minor upgrades cannot be run
>   simply by clicking on the .msi
>   file—they give the error: "Another
>   version of this product is already
>   installed." We know, stupid... Anyway,
>   you have to start it with the command:
>
> msiexec /i SampleUpgrade2.msi
>   REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus
>
> Don't ask me how this would fare with
>   the average user... You'd better start
>   it from an Autorun.inf file or devise
>   an outer Setup.exe shell to launch it.

We want people to be able to download the most recent version of our app and install it, even if they have an older version already installed.  How do you normally deal with this?

Comment: I'm curious why you are not simply using major upgrades?

Comment: Well, fixing a couple of bugs does not justify jumping from version 1.0.0 to version 2.0.0.

Comment: what he means is, just force the system to use a major upgrade, even if the actual version number is smaller than that.

Comment: Yep: I'm currently trying major upgrades even for upgrading from yesterday's dev build to today's dev build, which have the same version number (ignoring the 4th version field - as MSI does). I'm new to WiX/MSI so not sure if I should wholeheartedly recommend that, but if the effects of such an upgrade (uninstalls old version completely) are acceptable to you...

Comment: Please link the tutorial http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson4.php in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One word: bootstrapper. The WiX toolset has a simple bootstrapper right now (John Robbin's has a nice write up about [setupbld.exe](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/02/27/creating-a-bootstrap-loader-with-wix-3-0.aspx)).  In the future, Burn will do this and more.

Comment: Sorry @Rob the link to `setupbld.exe` is now broken

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised Rob didn't answer with the same answer as he did to my question, as it was basically the same question:

[WiX-- always overwrite the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775259/wix-always-overwrite-the-previous-version)

Comment: There are 2 valid answers. One is that it is only in very rare cases that a Minor Upgrade or Small update are actually justified. The second is that in those very rare cases the way to go about it is to use a bootstrapper or bundle application to properly invoke MSI.