# Duplicate symbol error when adding InstallExecuteSequence "RemoveExistingProducts" to WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <RemoveExistingProducts Before='InstallInitialize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I added this XML in order to force my application to uninstall previous versions as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732290/how-do-i-make-a-wix-msi-always-remove-a-previous-version), but I get the following error.

Is there somewhere this could have been declared that's not in my product.wxs file?

```
Error    34    Duplicate symbol 'WixAction:InstallExecuteSequence/RemoveExistingProducts' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.    \\psf\Home\Documents\eThor\Connector\WixInstaller\Product.wxs    6    1    WixInstaller
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a MajorUpgrade element in your wxs.  This element has an attribute that serves as syntactical sugar for authoring several rows including where to schedule RemoveExistingProducts.

Comment: I have a Schedule attribute with a value afterInstallFinalize in my MajorUpgrade element. Still no luck.