# Wix Bootstrapper Managed Application Upgrade Issue

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

i am working on a Wix Bootstrapper installer with the Managed Application UI that i am developing in .NET.

The problem is that i cant find anywhere what should be the functionality of 'Upgrading the Bootstrapper' from Program and features.
I have changed the Version of bundle from 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.0.0 but it still creates a separate entry in the Program and Features instead of Upgrading the old installed version.

So, what i guess is that there is some missing functionality that i need to provide in the Run() function so the installer knows what to do when it find a previous version installed.

Anyone who can help in this? i ll be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: There are open source projects using WiX on GitHub. Search for examples, and the answer might already be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at the following posts?

[How do I make a WIX MSI always remove a previous version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732290/how-do-i-make-a-wix-msi-always-remove-a-previous-version)

[how to get wix to update a previously installed version of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500703/how-to-get-wix-to-update-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-program)

The most popular answers above are setting the Product Id to be regenerated everytime and ensuring the Upgrade GUID constant. There are other tweaks, but you might want to read the posts to see if it applies to you or not.

```
<Product Id="*" ...>
```