# WiX Bootstrapper - Minor Upgrade

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have a bootstrapper which is built using Burn and installs a package which i have setup to allow for minor upgrades when i run the msi packages using REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus from the command prompt (as per [this](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/checking-for-oldies) article in the WiX docs).

However currently trying to upgrade with the setup.exe returns the message "Another version of this product is already installed..."

How do i get the boosttrapper to upgrade it's packages?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638586/automating-wix-small-updates-and-minor-upgrades) question from 2009 burn "will be able" do the work of starting the MSI in the appropriate mode can it do it now?

I have tried using the MsiProperty element like this:

```
<MsiPackage Id="PackageId" SourceFile="path\to\my.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name="REINSTALL" Value="ALL"/>
    <MsiProperty Name="REINSTALLMODE" Value="vomus"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

But that doesn't seem to do it. What have i Missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a minor upgrade Burn will automatically detect that and
pass the right switches for you. If you are trying to force it Burn does not support that.

Comment: Great, thanks! i am just trying to get it to do an upgrade. Am i right in thinking it uses the version numbers to detect when one is necessary? I think that might be where i was getting tripped up...

Comment: Yes so it goes major.minor.build any over numbers past the first 3 are ignored. so for a minor update you would change the minor number.